# zsh: command not found: laravel - How to fix

Tags: laravel, macos

The issue of installing laravel for the first time using a composer like this :

```
composer global require laravel/installer
```

then after you get the success messages and you be happy to run be a normal human and open a new tab and run :

```
laravel
```

in a new menu you will get this error in the title :

```
zsh: command not found: laravel
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This because **the composer bin directory is not a part of the system path** and this is always happening I have never seen someone not getting this error and spending hours trying to fix it.

Anyway, this means that you will need to go to your composer directory like that:

```
~/.composer/vendor/bin/laravel
```

this way, you will find it but it is not convenient always.

So you will need to add this to your path: `~/.composer/vendor/bin/`

if you cd there and maybe use the full path like this :

cd `~/.composer/vendor/bin/` then `pwd` and use the full path rather than the shorthand one.

it should look something like this : `/Users/someName/.composer/vendor/bin`

now copy the path. I will be adding it to the path file using vim :

So while you are in the bin directory :

we write: `sudo vim /etc/paths` remember there is a space after the world `vim`
Now the vim editor will open with the current paths, to insert the new path click letter `i`
and past the full path there ( `/Users/someName/.composer/vendor/bin` )

Once you're done, press the escape key Esc to get out of insert mode and back to command mode.

Type `:wq` to save and exit your file.

Now if you open a brand new tab in the terminal you should have access to `laravel`

Comment: Editing the global paths file seems less than idea, why not add it to his $PATH via his zshrc or something instead?

Comment: I agree with you, Yes we can do that too. I just decided to add it to the other PATHS and I think we will have to do this :
`vim ~/.zshrc` and you can add it there at the full path of directories.

Answer (score 0):

**You need to add Composer's system-wide vendor PATH**

1. Open `.zshrc` file in vim - `vi ~/.zshrc`
2. Add this line at the end of the `zshrc` file - `PATH=“$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH”`
3. then save and exit - `:wq`

Comment: Missed adding `export` should be something like this 
`export PATH=“$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH”`

Answer (score 0):

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/installation#main-content

- composer global require laravel/installer
- open ~/.bash_profile export
- PATH="$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"
- source ~/.bash_profile

video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a6sVI8Demiw&ab_channel=LaravelGigs